# How should I paint a door different colors on each side?

Tags: painting

I want to paint a door different colors on each side.

How should I paint the edges?
Should I try a tapeline straight down the middle of the edge? Should I paint the edges the same color as the side opposite the stop?

Is there a common industry standard practice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Paint the edges the color of the side it opens.

Comment: ... because you won't see the edge from the other side.

Comment: This answer is much more useful with @SimonB 's explanation :-)

Comment: And just to stir the pot:  what color for a pocket door?  (my serious answer would be "same as the trim surrounding the door" )